# What is the alternative to deprecated SE dplyr verbs in a for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyeval

I'm used to using the SE versions of `dplyr` verbs in for loops and am wanting to transition to the new evaluation semantics, but I'm struggling.

In older dplyr versions I would do something like:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  "a", 2, "dog",
  "b", 1, "cat",
  "a", 2,  "cat"
)

for (i in names(df %>% select(x,z))){
  print(count_(df,i))
}

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x         n
  <chr> <int>
1 a         2
2 b         1
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  z         n
  <chr> <int>
1 cat       2
2 dog       1
```

I have tried various combinations of `quo`/`enquo`/`!!`/`!!!` and can't seem to make it work using `count()`.

Comment: Maybe `for (i in distinct(df %>% select(x, z))) {
    print(count(df, !!i))
}`

Comment: Did you mean `count()` or `count_()`? You use the latter but say you can't get the former to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sym` to turn the string into a symbol, then use `!!` to insert the symbol into the expression

```
for (i in names(df %>% select(x,z))){
  print(count(df, !!sym(i)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks MrFlick.  That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(nm in c("x", "z")){
    print(df %>% count(!!as.symbol(nm)))
}
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  x         n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 a         2
#2 b         1
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  z         n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 cat       2
#2 dog       1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a data pronoun `.data` available from **rlang**.  This pronoun is particularly useful when referring to column names with strings like you are here.

You can read more about it/see examples [at the **rlang** website](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/tidyeval-data.html) and at the end of the [**rlang** 0.4.0 release article](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/).

```
for (i in names(df %>% select(x,z))){
     print( count(df, .data[[i]]) )
}
```

Comment: `.data` has been available since the very first version of rlang ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's a great package called `wrapr` which has a function `let` that "allows execution of arbitrary code with substituted variable names".  The code is more verbose than using `!!`, but I find it much easier to understand and less susceptible to error.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  "a", 2, "dog",
  "b", 1, "cat",
  "a", 2,  "cat"
)

for (name in names(df)) {
  wrapr::let(
    alias = list(var = name),
    expr = {
        df %>%
          count(var) %>%
          print()
    }
  )
}
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   x         n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 a         2
#> 2 b         1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       y     n
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2     2
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   z         n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 cat       2
#> 2 dog       1
```